# Some classes not found after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter

I am preparing small demo application on `flutter` using `AndroidStudio` on `ubuntu`. Application was working fine, suddenly I upgraded my `flutter` by using `flutter upgrade` command.

Problem starts here when I am compiling the application again now the error generating on compile time is below:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:214:43: Error: Getter not found: 'UTF8'.
      var json = await response.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
                                          ^^^^
lib/main.dart:216:61: Error: Getter not found: 'JSON'.
      UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse.fromJson(JSON.decode(json));
                                                            ^^^^
Compiler failed on /home/akshay/AkshayRanosys/Flutter/RanoStack/rano_stack/lib/main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

As we can read in error message compiler is not able to find **UTF8** class and **JSON** class.

I have tried with setting some http versions in my pubspec.yaml file as:

```
http: ^0.11.3+16 or http: ^0.12.0
```

But not able to resolve the error

Could any one can share their experiences regarding this stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you made quite a big update.

Several months ago when Dart 2 final was released, all SCREAMING_CASE const identifiers were changed to lowerCamelCase to comply with the Dart style guide. (they were marked as deprecated for quite some time before the old ones were finally removed)

`utf8` instead of `UTF8` and `json` instead of `JSON` (there is now also a `jsonDecode`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was not aware of this big change. Thank you for your answer